# wp_mail_from_name don't work with variables

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to modify a wordpress plugin with this code to change the mail name, I would like to pass a variable taken from a form field entered by the user, but it seems that it does not work with variable string.

Can somebody explain me why?

```
function my_mail_from( $str )
{
    return 'noreply@mydomain.com';
}

function my_mail_from_name($val)
{
    return $sender;
}

                
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from','my_mail_from');             
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'my_mail_from_name');
```

where the variable $sender is the container of the field entered by the user by the user

Comment: In `my_mail_from_name()`, the variable `$sender` is a local variable. Where is it supposed to come from?

Comment: And how shall I do? I try to pass as function my_mail_from_name($val, $sender) but wordpress goes on crash

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution , the variable should be declared global

```
function my_mail_from($str)
{
    return 'noreply@mydomain.com';
}

function my_mail_from_name($val)
{
    global $val;
    return $val;
}

                
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from','my_mail_from');             
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'my_mail_from_name');
```

Comment: where does the global $val get defined from?